# SQL View export to CSV by SQLCMD - Excel format numbers from varchar fields to exponent syntax

Tags: sql, csv, sql-server-2005, sqlcmd, sql-view

I export data from a sql view (SQL Server 2005) with a sql job to a csv-file:

```
sqlcmd -W -s ";"  -E  -d master -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT *  FROM [DB].[NameOfView];" -o "\\Location\File.csv"
```

In the sql view is a field (Type Varchar(20)) with numbers which are often longer than 15 characters. For this field I just usa a simple statement:

```
SELECT Fieldname AS Name FROM DB
```

...nothing special.

When I open the csv file excel formats the field with the long number to a format with exponent syntax:

[image]

Is there a way to edit something in the query or the sqlcmd job to say excel not to do that? I'm thinking about define the result as text and not as number in sql or something like this (but it is already a varchar field and i also tried things like ''''+ Fieldname and s.o. ... -.-)

I'm not able to change something in excel because a lot of people should have access to the csv - otherwise all of them have to make settings in excel.

They should open the csv and everything looks fine (:

Thanks for your help/ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does

```
SELECT '"' + Fieldname + '"' AS Name FROM DB
```

not work? That should cause double quotes to appear in the .csv and Excel to treat it as text.

Edit: try

```
SELECT '"=""' + Fieldname + '"""' AS Name FROM DB
```

(The above answer assumes that double-quotes don't need further escaping in the SQL string, given that it uses single-quotes for text literals, so if no joy just check this. You are aiming for it to look like

"=""0.00000014567897354354"""

in the CSV)

See also https://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-comma-delimited-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string

Comment: it does, but then I see also the quotes in excel like: '1138024010424772'

Comment: Try SELECT '"=""' + Fieldname + '"""' AS Name FROM DB

Comment: Perfect, thank's :-) In excel the field shows the whole number without exponent syntax now